# Android gallery setting image from assest folder

Tags: android, gallery

I want to set images of my gallery using files in assest folder.

Comment: Updated my answer with URI example i had found previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following with an assets folder such as /assets/images/myimage.jpg

```
String imagePath =  "images/myimage.jpg"

Bitmap bmp = null;
try{
   InputStream is = getAssets().open(imagePath);        
   bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
}
catch(Exception exception)
{
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon_grey_box);
}
((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myimage)).setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myimage)).setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Just also thought, if your using GalleryView, and have a dataprovider then you might be able to format the image paths using

file://mnt/sdcard/imageassets/

I think there is also a way to access your apk assets folder, using a URI path, similar to

"android.resource://[package]/[res id]"

This explains it well.

http://androidbook.blogspot.com/2009/08/referring-to-android-resources-using.html